# Selecting where multiple conditions match SafeMysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to make this query work

```
$key = $db->getAll("SELECT `key` 
                    FROM `".PREFIX."user_stats` 
                    WHERE `article_id` = ?i 
                    AND `domain` = ?s 
                    AND `userid` = ?i", 
                $article_id, $domain,$userid);
```

i use SafeMySql and getAll is Helper function to get all the rows of resultset right out of query and optional arguments

i want to echo key where 3 other columns match the input.

with the above query i get output "Array" nothing else.

Comment: probably you need not getAll() but some other method. what is expected output?

Comment: @Your Common Sense, i tried with getRow which select single row but did not worked, exact output is just "Array" like this http://prntscr.com/dwuij1

unfortunately there is nothing in error log

Comment: try with getOne(). you should use the method that returns data in the expected format

Comment: @Your Common Sense, i actually did tried with getOne and also couple of more with no luck, any new query will be appreciated.

Comment: So start from asking yourself what you want to get from this query.

Comment: what does `var_dump($key);` display if you run it just after the getAll?

Comment: @ADyson it does actually print the row :  array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1743 (1) { ["keyy"]=> string(6) "rKSpxf" } }

Comment: @ADyson so there is not anything wrong with the query itself ? how can i get just the "rKSpxf" i mean only the key as output ?

Comment: it's an array with 1 index, and the index contains an object. So `echo $key[0]->keyy;` should do it I think.

Comment: @ADyson WOW Finally it was echo $key[0]->keyy; the whole time, i was doing echo $keyy; well thank you so much finally i can move to a next thing now. thanks again.

Comment: yeah there's no such variable as $keyy in your code, keyy is a property of another object :-). I will post as the answer, if you would please upvote and/or mark as the accepted answer I would be grateful, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The structure of the $key object returned from the database, which you gave in the comments is:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1743 (1) { ["keyy"]=> string(6) "rKSpxf" } }
```

This is an array with a single element at index 0. This element is an object with a single property "keyy".

Therefore to access the data and output it, you need to write:

```
echo $key[0]->keyy;
```

The `[0]` references the first index of the array, and the `->keyy` references the "keyy" property of the object in that index.

To make clearer what's going on, you could write it longhand like this:

```
$obj = $key[0]; //get the object out of the array
$prop = $obj->keyy; //get the property out of the object
echo $prop; //output the value of the property
```